# Problem with Trailhead "Get Hands-On with New Alert, Confirm, and Prompt Modules and Components"

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

I can't to complete challenge "Get Hands-On with New Alert, Confirm, and Prompt Modules and Components".
I'm pretty sure this challenge have a bug and I want to know I made a mistake or this is challenge have bug.

The assignment:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default
class recordCardQuickFiles extends LightningElement {
 @api
 recordId;
 onDeleteAllFilesButtonClick() {
  const confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all files?");
   if (confirmation) {
      //... proceed with
     //... Apex Logic to delete Files.
    //... We will not check this comment.
    }
  }
}
```

- Create a new Lightning Web component
- Name: recordCardQuickFiles
- Import LightningConfirm from "lightning/confirm"
- Replace the confirm method with the LightningConfirm method
- Message: "Are you sure you want to delete all files?"
- Variant: "headerless"
- Label: "Are you sure you want to delete all files?"

My solution:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import LightningConfirm from "lightning/confirm";
export default
class recordCardQuickFiles extends LightningElement {
    @api
    recordId;
    configs = {
        Message: "Are you sure you want to delete all files?",
        Label: "Are you sure you want to delete all files?",
        Variant: "headerless"
    }
    onDeleteAllFilesButtonClick() {
        const confirmation = LightningConfirm.open(this.configs);
        if (confirmation) {
            //... proceed with
            //... Apex Logic to delete Files.
            //... We will not check this comment.
        }
    }
}
```

**And error occured: Challenge not yet complete in your.org
The Message used in the LightningConfirm method is not correct.**

Comment: You are new here. Stackoverflow is a manual to search info clear doubt. When you place your lesson looks like you want someone to do your job. This is not cool. Just a tip, think someone will be help with my exclusive lesson solved?

Comment: @AloisoJunior hi, it isn't my job task. I need complete this challenge that continue JS certification. But I'm pretty sure this challenge have a bug and I want to know I make a mistake or this is challenge bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JS file for the LWC should be something like the following:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import LightningConfirm from 'lightning/confirm';

export default
class recordCardQuickFiles extends LightningElement {
    @api
    recordId;
    onDeleteAllFilesButtonClick() {
        const confirmation = LightningConfirm.open({
            Message: 'Are you sure you want to delete all files?',
            Variant: 'headerless',
            Label: 'Are you sure you want to delete all files?'
        });
        if (confirmation) {
            //... proceed with
            //... Apex Logic to delete Files.
            //... We will not check this comment.
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, also I used async await in method and it worked!

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Its annoying that they expect a very specific code.